# Why is using bind returning "native code" in this mozilla JS dev tool?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing some JS to proof out some concepts, as I'm a newbie trying to learn JS and Node for work. I've written the following on the mozilla dev site demo screen (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind, no real significant reason for using it other than I've found it very convenient to do quick POCing like this one):

[screenshot-mozilla.img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiOdc.png)

As you can see I am trying to understand how bind works. In my last segment of code, I have:

```
var funcagain = foo["bar"];
console.log(funcagain.bind(foo, 'whiskey'));
```

And the output in the demo tool is:

```
> function () { [native code] }
```

I was expecting the output to be able to use the bind functionality and pick up **foo** as the *this-arg* and have the output: **a-awhiskey**

Why was this not the case and instead I got some unexpected output?

Comment: You're logging the function itself, you're not calling the function.

Comment: You have to add `()` to call the function: `console.log(funcagain.bind(foo, 'whiskey')());`

Comment: Just like the example on the website.

Comment: You're right. Thank you @barmar, i needed the () to actually have the func execute.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand is that the `.bind()` method actually returns a function which can be used later with the **binded** context.

You have to invoke that returned function to see the output you desire

or

you can use the `.call()` or `.apply()` to execute them immediately.

Let's try to see how a bind actually works

```js
Function.prototype.myBind = function(context) {
 var self = this;
 return function () {  
  return self.apply(context);
 }
}

window.foo = 1;

var testContext = {
 foo: 123
};

function oldFunc () {
 console.log(this.foo);
}

var newFunc = oldFunc.myBind(testContext);

newFunc();
```

This is a real dummy implementation of the bind function but I hope you understand now how the context is being passed to the function and saved for the later usage.

For a proper polyfill, please refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

Comment: He just forgot to call the function, it was a simple typo.